# What is the meaning of “Here goes" or “Here it goes"?

Tags: spoken-english, learning

I am quite confused about how to use, "Here goes” or "Here it goes". For example, what, if anything, is the meaning of the following phrase:

> Here goes nothing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "so here it goes?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51703/how-to-use-so-here-it-goes)

Comment: Welcome Petch! I'm going to edit your question because I think your spelling off the phrases is incorrect. If I'm wrong, you can always change it back.

Comment: @Fermichen is correct in that there is a potential duplicate, but I think that other question has so much else in it as well that it might be difficult for some non-fluent speakers (or even fluent speakers in a hurry!) to easily get to the parts relevant to this specific question. So I think it's reasonable to retain this more focused version. Just pre-empting any close-as-duplicate votes  

Answer (score 1):

They're all quite informal phrases, so it's difficult to explain why they mean what they do. They just do!

Taking your main example, I found one online [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/here%20goes%20nothing) which says the phrase is:

> used when one is about to try doing something new, difficult, or unpleasant

That's not bad, but I would add a little more. If someone said to me, "Here goes nothing" I'd assume that whatever it was they were about to try, they **did not expect to succeed** (or, at very least, they did not want **me** to expect them to succeed. )

Note that I changed your original, where you had "Here goes **nowhere**". However, you did specifically ask if that meant anything, so maybe you did mean "nowhere" after all. If so, then the answer is, no, it doesn't mean anything. Or at least it's not a form of words I've ever seen (and Google seems to agree with me).